# "Last-Modified" header gone missing when receiving in the client end from the Python Flask Rest API

Tags: python, flask, http-headers

I have a Flask Based python REST API, my issue is when I returning the response with the headers including the header `Last-Modified` it is gone missing when it receives to the client end, But all the other headers are present. I wonder how only that header is gone missing.

***Here is my code:***

```
def get_response:
  headers = {
    'Last-Modified': last_modified_after,  Wed, 04 Dec 2019 01:47:01 GMT #
    'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
    'Name': 'Test'
  }
  if user_has_old_version:
    return cloud_doc, HTTPStatus.OK, headers
  else:
    return cloud_doc, HTTPStatus.NOT_MODIFIED, headers
```

When I get the response for the **else** condition I only get the `Cache-Control` header and the custom `Name` header, this `Last-Modified` gone missing. But when I receive the **if** true case, I'm getting all the headers including the `Last-Modified` header.